# Zend Framework 2: Create Search Widget for Layout

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a small private Project to learn ZF2. I have integrated `Zend Lucene` as a `Search Function`. This works well, but I now want to integrate a Search Field in my Layout, so that it is available on all pages. I am really not sure how to achieve this. First of all, am I correct that this is done with a `View Helper`? As you can see below, I have got no idea what I have to enter into the `__invoke()` of my Helper to display my `Search Form`. Is my way correct in general or is there a better way? I would like a good `ZF2` solution, can someone give me some advice? Thank you very much in advance.

Okay, what have I done so far:

**1. I created a Form:**

```
namespace Advert\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class SearchForm extends Form
{

  public function __construct()
  {     
    parent::__construct('search');

    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'query',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'type'  => 'text',
                    'id' => 'queryText',
                    'required' => 'required'
                ),
                'options' => array(
                          'label' => 'Search String',
                ),
      ));

            $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'submit',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'type'  => 'submit',
                    'value' => 'Search'
                ),
            ));
      }
}
```

**2. created a View Helper DisplaySearchForm.php !!! 2. UPDATE !!!**

**A BIG Thank you to AlexP for his help !!!**

```
namespace Advert\View\Helper;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\Form\ElementInterface;

class DisplaySearchForm extends AbstractHelper
{
   protected $form;

   public function __construct($form)
   {
      $this->form = $form;
   }

   public function __invoke($form = null)
   {
      if ($form) {
        $this->form = $form;
      }
      return $this->render($this->form);
   }

   public function render($form)
   {
     // return $this->getView()->form($form);
     // To use my own Style, I have added a Partial
     return $this->getView()->render('partial/search', array('form' => $form));

   } 
}
```

I read somewhere that it would not be good to use the ServiceLocator in the Helper, so I thought about doing that in a Factory, where I will then get the Form. So I created a Factory (not sure the Factory is right)

**3. created Factory**

```
namespace Advert\View\Helper;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class DisplaySearchFormFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        $form = $realServiceLocator->get('FormElementManager')->get('\Advert\Form\SearchForm');
        $helper = new DisplaySearchForm($form);
        return $helper;
    } 
}
```

**4. I registered the Factory in the module.php**

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
           'displaySearchForm' => 'Advert\View\Helper\DisplaySearchForm',
         )
    )
 }
```

**5. In my Layout layout.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->displaySearchForm(); ?>
```

Comment: What you have looks good; including the factory. Do you have an issue?

Comment: Actually looking at the config, the factory should be registered as `Advert\View\Helper\DisplaySearchFormFactory`, not `Advert\View\Helper\DisplaySearchForm`. I guess you forgot to change it when you created the factory.

Comment: Thank you for your hint ! No Error Message just that I do not get the Form shown, which makes sense since I will still need somewhere echo $this->formElement($form->get('query')); and echo $this->formElement($form->get('submit')); and I suppose that is whyt need to go into the __invoke() of the View Helper, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AbstractHelper` has a `getView()` which returns the 'renderer'. This means you can use all the view helpers you need, as if you were in a view script.

The new helper could look like this.

```
use Zend\Form\ElementInterface;

class DisplaySearchForm extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $element; // Form element to render

    public function __construct(ElementInterface $element)
    {
        $this->element = $element;
    }

    public function __invoke($element = null)
    {
        if ($element) {
            $this->element = $element;
        }
        return $this->render($this->element);
    }

    public function render(ElementInterface $element)
    {
        return $this->getView()->form($element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, Thank you so much. It's not working yet, because of the constructor, but hopefully I work it out. Error Message now is:  "Argument 1 passed to Advert\View\Helper\DisplaySearchForm::__construct() must be an instance of Advert\View\Helper\ElementInterface, instance of Advert\Form\SearchForm given" which makes sense, because that is what I return in my Factory.... But thank you for the direction.

Comment: @Luka `ElementInterface` is an alias for `Zend\Form\ElementInterface`, I've added the `use` statement in the answer which will fix your error.

Comment: Oh God, I am such an idiot. Of course, sorry for that. But am I seeing it right that this will only return 1 input field (1 Element) and not the whole form ? As you can see it did not fully click yet... Sorry and Thanks so much!

Comment: I have updated the above Code. I think I have to add the $form in my constructor not an element, because that is what comes through the Factory. Correct me if I am wrong. The Error is now in the render Function, since it does not render the full Form and I should not work with echo here. Am I now on the right way? I am still not sure

Comment: @Luka The form *implements* `Zend\Form\ElementInterface` therefore it *is* an element and will pass the type hint. The idea is for reusable code, unless you have any reason to be more specific, doing it this way you can have any form element rendered not just a form. The line `$this->getView()->formElement($element)` is [a view helper that will introspect the class type and use the correct helper depending on what was passed in](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormElement.php).

Comment: Ok, now I am totally lost. With your solution, all I am getting is <input type="text" value="" name="search">. I have not even got an Element like that in the form. I am definitely missing something here, but can not get my heard around it. Do I need a Partial?

Comment: The updated code has a missing `protected $form` property deceleration at the top of the class, this may or may not be your issue. If it is the form you want to render (with it's elements) remove your current code from the render method and use just one line `return $this->getView()->form($form);`. Also make sure you return the value from the class and do the echo in the layout (e.g. `echo $this->displaySearchForm()`.)

Comment: Great Help. Thank you! Tried all day to find a solution, without your help, no chance.